# Исключить элемент из списка

Tags: android, kotlin

Получаю целиком следующий список:

```
 private fun collectParentItems(): List<Any> {
    val parentItems = collectParentCategoriesGuids().map { CategoriesListItem(it) }
    return if (parentItems.isEmpty()) emptyList() else parentItems
}
```

Как я могу по-прежнему получить целый список, но при этом исключить один(конкретный) элемент из него?

Comment: Сформулируйте условие, как определить что именно надо исключать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это можно сделать с помощью [перегруженного оператора `-`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/minus.html), который копирует последовательность в новый список, исключая первое вхождение данного элемента:

```
val list = listOf(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)
val result = list - 2
println(result) // [1, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

<sup>[(запускаемый пример)](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/1mlho86i6u75tpbjijfdr31506/dn7h15bgorvjkhchu90o7avlit)</sup>

Comment: Ну а в конкретно моём примере как можно это реализовать? Мне нужно именно строку убирать, но к сожалению по Вашему методу не совсем получается..

Comment: @Inkognito, то есть, нужно исключить из списка элемент, который создавался как `CategoriesListItem(x)`, зная `x`?